# Display scrollbars with reportviewer and asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reportviewer

I will be displaying 4 reports in one webform, so I would like to create a section of about 500x500px for each report and use the horizontal/vertical scrollbars to navigate each report.

I've tried wrapping the reportviewer in a div, iframe, panel, tablecell, but none of them can contain the report to that space. Here's the client-side code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="600">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

The following is the code-behind. I'm adding it because I've noticed that the way the report is generated makes a difference. Using the following link, [ASPNet-Report-Viewer-control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Report-Viewer-control-Tutorial-with-example.aspx), I noticed that the report is contained to the space if the report is generated within the report.

In my case, since it's a more complex BI report, the report is already generated. I just need to display it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<Server>/ReportServer");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/Daily.Reports/DailyDetail";
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = false;
        ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ended up displaying the reports in a tab control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up displaying the reports in a tab control.